# setTimeout with self executing function

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I want to write a self executing function within it. I have something like this:

```
var testObject= (function () {
function testObject() {
    this.counter = 0;
}

testObject.prototype.Cycle = function () {
    try {
        console.log("tick, ID: " + this.counter++);

        setTimeout(this.Cycle, 2000);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
};

return testObject;
})();
```

And it works only once. Because at the first run it gives `tick, ID: 0` and at the second time it gives `tick, ID: undefined`. What is the best way to achieve self executing function?

Comment: What is the try/catch supposed to achieve ?

Comment: [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think the IIFE matters in this question.

Comment: It doesn't, but just saying as it said self executing function in the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you have is that `this`, in the callback, is `window`.

A solution :

```
testObject.prototype.Cycle = function () {
    try {
        console.log("tick, ID: " + this.counter++);
        setTimeout(this.Cycle.bind(this), 2000);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
};
```

But you don't need all this code. You may simply do :

```
(function cycle(i){
    console.log("tick, ID: " + i);
    setTimeout(cycle, 2000, i+1);
})(0);
```